# Validate data when textbox loses focus

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my ASP.Net web application, there is a textbox to receive ProductId. When the user enters data into the ProductId textbox and moves to the next textbox, I want to validate the data against a table and if matching record is found, I want to display Product details in different controls (readonly and normal textboxes) else I want to display a message about "New Product" and continue. I do not want to do the verification AFTER the user enters all data and press the Save button, but it should be done immediately. I was hoping that the Web Form textbox would have a LostFocus event, but do not know how to handle the requirement.

Comment: ASP .NET is serverside, you are talking about a client side event. You will have to write some client side code to do what you want, perhaps with a roundtrip to the server via AJAX.

Comment: The ProductId being verified is at client side, but the data against which it will be verified is from the Database server. I am a newbie and have no experience with AJAX or jQuery. A few example will be a great learning experience for me.

Comment: Open Web Browser, Type in www.google.com.  In the search box - put in AJAX JQUERY ASP.NET and click search.  I tried this and got over 12 million results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET Validators don't have an ajax style immediate check.

1. Attach a custom validator to your textbox that hooks up to a validation method server side.
2. Using javascript, you'll need to hook up an eventhandler to the focusout event and make an ajax call. That call will send the value back to the server and get a response of valid or not.

This site : http://brian.dobberteen.com/code/jquery_ajax_custom_validator/ will help you with a lot of it, but one thing is this will fire only when the page is submitted. You'll want to hook up an additional event handler to your textbox to call the validation method on focusout

Answer (score 0):

It's easy solution, read this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.servervalidate.aspx

You just need to preform javascript call to trigger server validation, use event onlostfocus.

Comment: needs to be "client" side.